# Looping through with varied subtotal ranges

Tags: performance, beginner, vba, excel

I've got an issue where my looping through the rows on my sheet are extremely slow. For 20,000 rows, it takes about 20 minutes, whereas before, it was taking 3. The only pieces I added were at the very bottom, starting with the

```
for l = 2 to lastLet
```

and ending at the bottom of the code.

When I go to debug the code while running to see where it's at, I am surprised to find that the hangup isn't at these last lines, but rather that it sits in the middle of the code. Unfortunately it's for billing data so I can't share the sheet, but the data comes to me in a simple database format.To note, every piece of the code still works (and yes I know initializing variables is good practice), but is there a way to increase the performance on it?

**Is the addition I made to the code causing the slowing in run time or is it something else?**

Note: I don't have any formal education with programming or VBA. All information is self taught, so please use terminology I can understand~

```
Function Col_Letter(colInt As Integer) As String
' This function converts column numbers to their corresponding letters
Dim lett
lett = Split(Cells(1, colInt).Address(True, False), "$")
Col_Letter = lett(0)
End Function
```

`

```
Sub OpenBilling()
Dim lastLet As Integer
Sheets("Billing").Select
lastRow = Sheets("Billing").range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastLet = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastCol = Col_Letter(lastLet)
sort1 = Col_Letter(Sheets("Billing").range("1:1").Find("ccustname").Column)
sort2 = Col_Letter(Sheets("Billing").range("1:1").Find("cjobno").Column)
sort3 = Col_Letter(Sheets("Billing").range("1:1").Find("dinvdate").Column)
sort4 = Col_Letter(Sheets("Billing").range("1:1").Find("citemdesc").Column)
sort5 = Col_Letter(Sheets("Billing").range("1:1").Find("csort3").Column)
sort6 = Col_Letter(Sheets("Billing").range("1:1").Find("ninvamt").Column)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Billing").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Billing").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=range( _
sort1 & "2:" & sort1 & lastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Billing").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=range( _
sort2 & "2:" & sort2 & lastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
xlSortTextAsNumbers
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Billing").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=range( _
sort3 & "2:" & sort3 & lastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Billing").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=range( _
sort4 & "2:" & sort4 & lastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Billing").Sort
.SetRange range("A1:" & lastCol & lastRow)
.Header = xlYes
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With
Sheets("Billing").range("A:A").Insert (xlShiftToRight)
sort1 = Col_Letter(Sheets("Billing").range("1:1").Find("ccustname").Column)
sort2 = Col_Letter(Sheets("Billing").range("1:1").Find("cjobno").Column)
sort3 = Col_Letter(Sheets("Billing").range("1:1").Find("dinvdate").Column)
sort4 = Col_Letter(Sheets("Billing").range("1:1").Find("citemdesc").Column)
sort5 = Col_Letter(Sheets("Billing").range("1:1").Find("csort3").Column)
sort6 = Col_Letter(Sheets("Billing").range("1:1").Find("ninvamt").Column)
change1 = Sheets("Billing").range("1:1").Find("ninvamt").Address
Sheets("Billing").range("A1").Value = "Difference"
Sheets("Billing").range("A2").Value = "=IF(H2=H1,IF(OR((" & sort3 & "2-" & sort3 & "1)<(-1000),ISERROR(" & sort3 & "2-" & sort3 & "1)),""""," & sort3 & "2-" & sort3 & "1),0)"
Sheets("Billing").range("A2").Copy
Sheets("Billing").range("A2:A" & lastRow).PasteSpecial
Sheets("Billing").range("A1").Select
Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=Sheets("Billing").range("1:1").Find("cjobno").Column, Function:=xlSum, _
TotalList:=Array(Sheets("Billing").range("1:1").Find("ninvamt").Column), _
Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True

lastRow = Sheets("Billing").range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastLet = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Columns(sort3 & ":" & sort3).Select
Selection.Replace What:="  -   -", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
For i = 1 To lastRow
If Sheets("Billing").range(sort1 & i).Value = "" Then
Sheets("Billing").range(sort1 & i).Value = "=" & _
Sheets("Billing").range(sort1 & (i - 1)).Address
End If
If Sheets("Billing").range(sort5 & i).Value = "" Then
Sheets("Billing").range(sort5 & i).Value = "=" & _
Sheets("Billing").range(sort5 & (i - 1)).Address
End If
If Sheets("Billing").range("B" & i).Value = "" Then
endFor = Sheets("Billing").range(sort3 & (i - 1)).Address
If startFor = "" Then
startFor = "$" & sort3 & "$2"
Else: Sheets("Billing").range(sort3 & i).Value = "No Date"
End If
Sheets("Billing").range(sort3 & i).Value = "=Max(" & _
startFor & ":" & endFor & ")"
End If
If Sheets("Billing").range("B" & i).Value = "" Then
endFor = Sheets("Billing").range(sort3 & (i - 1)).Address
If startFor = "" Then
startFor = "$" & sort3 & "$2"
End If
startNum = range(startFor).Row
endNum = range(endFor).Row
maxRange = 0
currMax = 0
For k = endNum To startNum Step -1
If Sheets("Billing").range(sort3 & k).Value <> "" Or _
Sheets("Billing").range(sort3 & k).Value <> 0 Then
If maxRange < Sheets("Billing").range(sort3 & k).Value Then
currMax = Sheets("Billing").range(sort3 & k).Offset(0, 9).Value
maxRange = Sheets("Billing").range(sort3 & k).Value
End If
Else
End If
Next k
Sheets("Billing").range(sort3 & i).Offset(0, 9).Value = currMax
End If
If Sheets("Billing").range("B" & i).Value = "" Then
Sheets("Billing").range("B" & i).EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
End If
If Sheets("Billing").range("B" & i).Value = "" Then
endFor = Sheets("Billing").range(sort3 & (i - 1)).Address
If startFor = "" Then
startFor = "$" & sort3 & "$2"
End If
startNum = range(startFor).Row
endNum = range(endFor).Row
maxRange = 0
For j = endNum To startNum Step -1
If Sheets("Billing").range(sort3 & j).Value <> "" Or _
Sheets("Billing").range(sort3 & k).Value <> 0 Then
If maxRange < Sheets("Billing").range(sort3 & j).Value Then
currMax = Sheets("Billing").range(sort3 & j).Offset(0, 1).Value
maxRange = Sheets("Billing").range(sort3 & j).Value
End If
End If
Next j
Sheets("Billing").range(sort3 & i).Offset(0, 1).Value = currMax
startFor = Sheets("Billing").range(sort3 & (i + 1)).Address
End If
Next i
range(sort1 & "1").Value = "Builder"
range(sort5 & "1").Value = "Project Name"
range(sort2 & "1").Value = "Job Number"
range(sort3 & "1").Value = "Invoice Date"
range(sort4 & "1").Value = "Item Description"
Sheets("Billing").range(change1).Value = "Invoice Amount"
Columns.AutoFit
For l = 2 To lastLet
If Sheets("Billing").range(Col_Letter(CInt(l)) & "1").End(xlDown).Row < lastRow Then
Sheets("Billing").range(Col_Letter(CInt(l)) & ":" & Col_Letter(CInt(l))).ClearContents
End If
Next l
Dim delRange As range
Set delRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
For counter = delRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
If Application.CountA(Columns(counter).EntireColumn) = 0 Then
Columns(counter).Delete (xlShiftToRight)
End If
Next counter
MsgBox "The report has been completed."
End Sub
```

Comment: Declaring your variables will already remove the need for VBA to declare them on-the-fly as implicit `Variant`, which will in turn remove the need to perform on-the-fly implicit type conversions everywhere they're used, which should already help performance at least a tiny little bit. There's a reason why declaring all your variables is a good practice. If you *know* about it, then why aren't you doing it? Specify `Option Explicit` to prevent VBA from happily compiling typos and introducing hard-to-find and oh-so-frustrating bugs.

Comment: I would warmly recommend using [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) (a VBIDE add-in OSS project I manage) to help you with locating all undeclared variables *and properly indent your code with one single click*, enhancing readability ten-fold, pretty much effortlessly.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post so that it includes *at least* everything from `Sub ...` to `End Sub`?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Is it really that big of a performance difference using declared versus undeclared variables? Also, what's there is everything from Sub to End Sub, there's nothing special on those sides. As for your IDE, I usually manually indent my code, but had some......issues with my management that caused me to not have the time to change it, then left over a weekend. I appreciate the help and the IDE link!

Comment: Experience talking: you probably won't notice. Your users probably won't notice. It's not about performance, it's about *correctness* and *avoiding stupid typo-induced bugs that take an hour to find*. `Option Explicit` is your best friend here, trust me. I'm sure you'll love Rubberduck BTW!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First, kudos and welcome to the wonderful world of programming! I'm self-taught as well! One thing I've learned - and that's not specific to programming in any way - is that dumbing-down explanations serves no one: if there's anything in my post that isn't clear, feel free to ask. Also feel free to google up any terms you're possibly not familiar with.
>
> In other words I'll *try* to keep it accessible, but there won't be any *flowers & bees* here.

The first thing that strikes anyone looking at this code, is the sheer lack of breathing space, both vertical and horizontal: everything is crammed into a monolithic unindented block of procedural code that does everything that needs to happen: that procedure is a "God procedure", a *script* that essentially goes top-to-bottom sequentially, and that's all there is to it.

Whenever you see a chunk of code and think "that chunk of code does *X*" or "these 10 lines here are responsible for *Y*", the single best thing to do is to <s>add a comment that says what it does</s> *extract* it into its own, separate, dedicated procedure. Doing that will increase the *abstraction level* of your "main" procedure, making it progressively less and less concerned about every single little detail of what's going on, and more and more about the *big picture*: once you're done splitting it up, you should be able to read that "main" procedure as a series of operations, and *at a glance* know *what* it does, without necessarily knowing *how* it does it.

---

You **never** need to work out the "letter" of a column. Never. Kill `Col_Letter` with fire, and don't look back.

When you know the column index you need to work with, instead of concatenating it with a row number to use it with `Range`, use it directly with `Cells` (which *also* happens to return a `Range` object), which uses row and column numbers.

Side note, avoid underscores in procedure names. The underscore has a special meaning in VBA code, and when you get to a more advanced level they can bite you in the rear end and literally prevent your code from compiling. Stick to `PascalCase` and everything will be fine.

---

I did a quick search on this page for `Sheets("Billing")`, and my browser finds **62 instances**.

That means you're dereferencing **the same object** 62 times. And you're not consistent with how you're doing it; sometimes it's through the `Sheets` collection, *implicitly* off the `ActiveWorkbook`:

```
sort6 = Col_Letter(Sheets("Billing").range("1:1").Find("ninvamt").Column)
```

Other times it's through the `Worksheets` collection, *explicitly* off the `ActiveWorkbook`:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Billing").Sort.SortFields.Clear
```

Interesting that these two lines are one after the other.

Other times you're just working off the `ActiveSheet` explicitly - but it's the same object reference again, since the sheet was `.Select`ed:

```
lastLet = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

If that `Billing` sheet is part of `ThisWorkbook` (the workbook that contains this code), then give it a *code name* - select the worksheet in the VBE's *Project Explorer*, and hit F4 to bring up the *Properties* toolwindow, and change its `(Name)` property to, say, `BillingSheet`. Note that if anything in your code is referencing the sheet's current `CodeName`, renaming it that way will break your code.

Or, right-click it in [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com)'s *Code Explorer*, and select "Rename" - Rubberduck will change its `CodeName` property for you, and if anything in your code is using that `CodeName` identifier, it will also be updated.

Then, *use it*. Instead of this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Billing").Sort.SortFields.Clear
```

Do this:

```
BillingSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
```

> **How does that work?**
>
> By setting the `(Name)` property of the worksheet to `BillingSheet`, VBA creates a globally-scoped object variable named after the value of that property. By default that's e.g. `Sheet1`, but you can change that and use this free global object variable everywhere, instead of dereferencing that very same object every time from a collection.

---

Next thing to do is to remove all `.Select` calls and anything that's working with `Selection`:

```
Sheets("Billing").range("A1").Select
Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=Sheets("Billing").range("1:1").Find("cjobno").Column, Function:=xlSum, _
TotalList:=Array(Sheets("Billing").range("1:1").Find("ninvamt").Column), _
Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
```

Instead, work with the `Worksheet` and `Range` objects you have:

```
BillingSheet.Range("A1").Subtotal _
    GroupBy:=BillingSheet.Range("1:1").Find("cjobno").Column, _
    Function:=xlSum, _
    TotalList:=Array(BillingSheet.Range("1:1").Find("ninvamt").Column), _
    Replace:=True, _
    PageBreaks:=False, _
    SummaryBelowData:=True
```

Notice how much easier that is to read!

```
For i = 1 To lastRow
If Sheets("Billing").range(sort1 & i).Value = "" Then
Sheets("Billing").range(sort1 & i).Value = "=" & _
Sheets("Billing").range(sort1 & (i - 1)).Address
End If
```

Indentation is your friend too:

```
For i = 1 To lastRow
    If BillingSheet.Cells(i, customerNameColumn).Value = "" Then
        BillingSheet.Range(i, customerNameColumn).Value = _
            "=" & BillingSheet.Range(i - 1, customerNameColumn).Address
    End If
    '...
```

In your code, I have no idea where that loop block ends, and I don't have the patience to look for it.

Undeclared variables are a plague, too: unless I quadruple-check everything I do (who has time for that?), I can't be sure I won't be introducing a bug by moving a `startFor` assignment somewhere else, or just rearranging the code.

This isn't about performance, it's about maintainability. Code like this is unmaintainable. Over time, the only thing that can possibly happen, is that it rots and starts collecting bugs, and as old bugs are fixed, new subtle ones inevitably get introduced.

There's one right here:

```
    If BillingSheet.Cells(i, customerNameColumn).Value = "" Then
```

If `BillingSheet.Cells(i, customerNameColumn).Value` contains an Excel error value (e.g. `#N/A` or `#VALUE!`, or whatever), then that conditional will be blowing up with run-time error 13 / *Type Mismatch*, because you can't legally compare an `Error` to a `String` - or anything actually. Any time you read a cell value, you should wrap it with an `IsError` function call first, to make sure the call won't blow up on you because some user deleted a column, or something on the worksheet is dividing by zero, or a lookup failed somewhere, or whatever.

That's as far as I'll go.

You can definitely improve the performance of that code, but doing that without first addressing the readability/maintainability issues would be dangerous.

You can use `Union` to combine the entire rows you want to delete, and delete them all at once, instead of looping backwards and recalculating the entire worksheet every time.

Oh, well there's an easy way to improve performance - *prevent* Excel from constantly recalculating everything every time you change a cell, and heck, prevent it from repainting and firing worksheet events every time, too:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' do stuff

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic ' triggers recalc
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

That should help quite a lot, but you definitely want to break up that procedure into smaller chunks, declare every variable, indent everything properly, and stop querying worksheet collections all the time.

I hope to see a new question soon, with the revised code!