# Invoice archival sheet

Tags: beginner, vba, excel

I have a workbook I use for archiving basic invoice data that I created for my parents. Unlike [my other disaster of code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/176648/looping-through-with-varied-subtotal-ranges/176654#176654), I properly indented and tried my best to condense the code and increase performance. My issue is that it is still in a single block of code, but I'm not sure how to go about breaking up code, and it seems like having everything in the same place as is makes it easier to pull from the various sections of the report. That being said, I'm still a beginner and have limited programming experience.

**How can I determine where to split my god code into more manageable modules?**

```
Option Explicit

' Please note this VBA was created by ------------.
' Please provide credit when copying or using for other purposes.

Sub CompanyArchive()

' Lets the code know where to go in case of Errors
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler1
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Initializes all variables to prevent name misuse
Dim pRangeFind As Range
Dim iNumCell As String
Dim eStartCell As String
Dim eLastRow As Integer
Dim eLastCell As String
Dim eCopyRange As String
Dim qRangeFind As Range
Dim jNumCell As String
Dim fStartCell As String
Dim fLastRow As Integer
Dim fLastCell As String
Dim fCopyRange As String
Dim rRangeFind As Range
Dim kNumCell As String
Dim gStartCell As String
Dim gLastRow As Integer
Dim gLastCell As String
Dim gCopyRange As String
Dim aLastCell As Integer
Dim aInvoiceCell As String
Dim aDateStartCell As String
Dim aDateLength As Integer
Dim aDateLastCell As String
Dim aDatePasteRange As String
Dim nameFind As Range
Dim shipName As String
Dim aShipStartCell As String
Dim aShipEndCell As String
Dim aShipPasteRange As String
Dim Infobox1 As Object
Dim Infobox2 As Object
Dim Infobox3 As Object
Dim Infobox4 As Object

' Finds and sets the invoices to be copied to the archive
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoices").Range("B:B")
    Set pRangeFind = .Find(What:="Invoice Number:", _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
    iNumCell = pRangeFind.Offset(1, 0).Address
End With
eStartCell = Sheets("Invoices").Range(iNumCell).Address
eLastRow = Sheets("Invoices").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
eLastCell = Sheets("Invoices").Range("B" & eLastRow).Address
eCopyRange = Sheets("Invoices").Range(eStartCell & ":" & eLastCell).Address

' Finds and sets the part numbers to be copied to the archive
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoices").Range("C:C")
    Set qRangeFind = .Find(What:="Shipping Content:", _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
    jNumCell = qRangeFind.Offset(1, 0).Address
End With
fStartCell = Sheets("Invoices").Range(jNumCell).Address
fLastRow = Sheets("Invoices").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
fLastCell = Sheets("Invoices").Range("C" & fLastRow).Address
fCopyRange = Sheets("Invoices").Range(fStartCell & ":" & fLastCell).Address

' Finds and sets the quantity of parts to be copied to the archive
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoices").Range("D:D")
    Set rRangeFind = .Find(What:="Quantity:", _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
    kNumCell = rRangeFind.Offset(1, 0).Address
End With
    If Sheets("Invoices").Range(kNumCell).Value = "" Then GoTo ErrorHandler3 
Else
gStartCell = Sheets("Invoices").Range(kNumCell).Address
gLastRow = Sheets("Invoices").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
gLastCell = Sheets("Invoices").Range("D" & gLastRow).Address
gCopyRange = Sheets("Invoices").Range(gStartCell & ":" & gLastCell).Address

' Finds the bottom of the archives data
aLastCell = Sheets("Archives").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
aInvoiceCell = Sheets("Archives").Range("B" & (aLastCell + 1)).Address
aDateStartCell = Sheets("Archives").Range(aInvoiceCell).Offset(0, -1).Address
aDateLength = Sheets("Invoices").Range(eLastCell).Row - Sheets("Invoices").Range(eStartCell).Row
aDateLastCell = Sheets("Archives").Range(aDateStartCell).Offset(aDateLength, 0).Address
aDatePasteRange = Sheets("Archives").Range(aDateStartCell & ":" & aDateLastCell).Address

' Finds the bottom of the name data and adds the name to the column
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoices").Range("B:B")
    Set nameFind = .Find(What:="Ship To:", _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
    shipName = nameFind.Offset(0, 1).Value
aShipStartCell = Sheets("Archives").Range(aDateStartCell).Offset(0, 2).Address
aShipEndCell = Sheets("Archives").Range(aDateLastCell).Offset(0, 2).Address
aShipPasteRange = Sheets("Archives").Range(aShipStartCell & ":" & aShipEndCell).Address
Sheets("Archives").Range(aShipPasteRange).Value = shipName
End With

' Copies the data and pastes it to the Archives
Sheets("Invoices").Range("C9").Copy
Sheets("Archives").Range(aDatePasteRange).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Sheets("Invoices").Range(eCopyRange).Copy
Sheets("Archives").Range(aInvoiceCell).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Sheets("Invoices").Range(fCopyRange).Copy
Sheets("Archives").Range(aInvoiceCell).Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Sheets("Invoices").Range(gCopyRange).Copy
Sheets("Archives").Range(aInvoiceCell).Offset(0, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

' Notates code completion to the user and wraps up the code
Sheets("Invoices").Select
Set Infobox4 = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Select Case Infobox4.Popup("The code has run successfully." _
    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please click OK to close this message.", 5, "Congratulations!", 0)
    Case 1, -1
End Select
LastLine:
Sheets("Invoices").Range("D7:D9").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub
' This is where the code will go to if a general error occurs. It will show an error message and end the code.
ErrorHandler1:
    Set Infobox1 = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Select Case Infobox1.Popup("An error has occurred while running the report." _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please contact your analyst with the below error" _
        & vbCrLf & "and please do not run the macro again." _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Error #:" & Err.Number _
        & vbCrLf & Err.Description _
        & vbCrLf & "Click OK to close this message.", 5, "Not like this...", 0)
    Case 1, -1
    GoTo LastLine
End Select

' This is where the code will go to if there is no data. It will show an error message and end the code.
ErrorHandler2:
    Set Infobox2 = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Select Case Infobox2.Popup("There is no data for the code to use." _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please add data and try again.", 5, "Not like this...", 0)
    Case 1, -1
    GoTo LastLine
End Select

' This is where the code will go to if there is information missing. It will show an error message and end the code.
ErrorHandler3:
    Set Infobox3 = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Select Case Infobox3.Popup("There is not enough information to archive." _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please add data and try again.", 5, "Not like this...", 0)
    Case 1, -1
    GoTo LastLine
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: you already have it - split on the comments

Comment: @SeanC If I did that, I'd need to reinitialize most of my variables at every turn, making calls that I otherwise wouldn't/

Comment: although some people don't like it, you could declare the variables as global by declaring them outside of the subroutine. If you need to keep what is in them hidden, declare them as `private`

Answer (score 2):

These are repeated three time with different names

```
eStartCell
eLastRow
eLastCell
eCopyRange
```

That makes a good case for a Function

```
Private Function GetSheetInformation(ByVal targetSheet As Worksheet, ByVal startingCell As Range, ByVal targetColumn As String) As Variant
    Dim dataArray(1 To 4) As Variant

    dataArray(1) = targetSheet.Range(startingCell).Address
    dataArray(2) = targetSheet.Range(targetColumn & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    dataArray(3) = targetSheet.Range(targetColumn & dataArray(2)).Address
    dataArray(4) = targetSheet.Range(dataArray(1) & ":" & dataArray(2)).Address

    GetSheetInformation = dataArray
End Function
```

Use it for each target like

```
Dim firstRangeData As Variant
firstRangeData = GetSheetInformation(Sheets("Invoices"), kNumCell, "D")
```